# ASP.NET MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I have only default route enabled:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Which will resove paths like: hostname/Home/Index, hostname/Home/Foo, hostname/Home/Bar/23 just fine.
But I must also enable route like this: hostname/{id} which should point
to:
**Controller:** Home
**Action:** Index
**{id}:** Index action parameter "id"

Is such a route even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not Tested : 
Create your route like this

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "custom",
        url: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

under your default route

Comment: That just killed all my AJAX calls :)

Comment: what's url u r request in ajax?

Comment: I have couple of them: /Home/Register/{param}, /Home/Login/{param}, etc

Comment: the route i have given you is after the default route also name should be changed

Answer (score 1):

If `id` is a number you could add a route **above** the other one and define a regex constraint:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "IdOnlyRoute",
    url: "{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
    constraints: new { id = "^[0-9]+$" }
);
```

Comment: Nope, it's a string :)

Comment: If it is a string with some particular constraints, you can still use the solution above... if it is just a string like anything else then you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm short on time, I have configured route for every action. Luckly there are not many of them. :)

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "IndexWithParam",
            url: "{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "IndexWithOutParam",
            url: "",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "Home/Login",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login" }
        );
```

So last route was repeated for ever other action. Not sure if it can be done better, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to play around with [AttributeRouting](http://attributerouting.net/) package?

Then your code will look like this

```
    [GET("/{id}", IsAbsoluteUrl = true)]
    public ActionResult Index(string id) { /* ... */ }
```